# method does not override method from its superclass on onActivityResult for selecting image from Gallery

Tags: android

[image]

I don't understand and there are no docs whatsoever to be found on this.

What do you do to get an image selection right?

I'm following this video series and getting nowhere because for some reason 100% of all android code got deprecated in two year's time.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpwivlI7tzo&list=PL73qvSDlAVVh5MO1Bfujfb_SDPABjJ2BY&index=17

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xIWkCJZCu0&list=PL73qvSDlAVVh5MO1Bfujfb_SDPABjJ2BY&index=15

I don't get it what can you do to get around this?

are you supposed to have the code that controls your view in a View?

in a Fragment?

in an Activity?

in the MainActivity?

I've tried all and none of them don't throw this error.

I'd be satisfied with being pointed to a decent guide or docs. I've been furiously googling all day and coming up short.

android's docs (these I suppose ) : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#java

don't factor in any human needs and realistic scenarios.

nor does it care about the returned file and displaying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) has no parameter `context` hence the issue so remove `, Context context`

e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, 
                int resultCode, 
                Intent data){//..code}
```

**Note :** `@Override` implies various rules on overridden methods and one of them is

*The argument list should be exactly the same as that of the overridden method*

Comment: ok thanks. (also what in the hell is wrong with Java's error messages and why can't they just be normal like everyone else's ?) but that just brings me back to the issue of not being able to  call `.getContentResolver().openInputStream(` nor  `Toast.makeText(this`
because context is missing

Comment: you can directly call `getContentResolver()` in your activity or you need context object either via constructor or some other way, where are you using it

Comment: I still can't get over how easy it would have been for Java to tell me there was a wrong number of arguments. Java was the language I started with, I used to love it, now I can't believe I ever did.

Comment: yes, that's the easy one, but if it is a fragment then you can use getActivity or getContext (after oncreate) otherwise you have to pass context object somehow. it happens just keep it up

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult` is used to receive the result for the execution of an `Activity` that has been called from current `Activity` using `startActivityForResult`. It is independent of `Context` of `Activity` for which it is receiving result, because it has `requestCode`, `resultCode` to determine uniqueness of response and it also contains response data as `Intent`. Here is the syntax.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){//code}
```